# Type '{ visibility: string; 'line-join': string; 'line-cap': string; } | { visibility: string; }' is not assignable to type

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, mapbox-gl-js

I am using mapbox with angular. And I try to show/hide some stuff with mapbox.

So I have this component:

```
export class ToggleLayersComponent implements OnInit {
  layouts = {
    contours: {
      visibility: 'visible',
      'line-join': 'round',
      'line-cap': 'round',
    },
    museums: {
      visibility: 'visible',
    },
  };

  ngOnInit() {}

  toggleLayer(evt: {value: 'contours' | 'museums'}) {
    this.layouts[evt.value] = {
      ...this.layouts[evt.value],
      visibility: this.layouts[evt.value].visibility === 'visible' ? 'none' : 'visible',
    };
  }
}
```

But I get this error:

```
Type '{ visibility: string; 'line-join': string; 'line-cap': string; } | { visibility: string; }' is not assignable to type '{ visibility: string; 'line-join': string; 'line-cap': string; } & { visibility: string; }'.
  Type '{ visibility: string; }' is not assignable to type '{ visibility: string; 'line-join': string; 'line-cap': string; } & { visibility: string; }'.
    Type '{ visibility: string; }' is missing the following properties from type '{ visibility: string; 'line-join': string;
```

Of course I googled first. But I can't find any solution.

So how to fix this?

Thank you

So the error is on this line:

```
 this.layouts[evt.value]
```

So I can't even run Angular anymore:

```
ERROR in src/app/desktop-dashboard/toggle-layer/toggle-layer.component.ts:63:5 - error TS2322: Type '{ visibility: string; 'line-join': string; 'line-cap': string; } | { visibility: string; }' is not assignable to type '{ visibility: string; 'line-join': string; 'line-cap': string; } & { visibility: string; }'.    
  Type '{ visibility: string; }' is not assignable to type '{ visibility: string; 'line-join': string; 'line-cap': string; } & { visibility: string; }'.      
    Type '{ visibility: string; }' is missing the following properties from type '{ visibility: string; 'line-join': string; 'line-cap': string; }': 'line-join', 'line-cap'

63     this.layouts[evt.value] = {
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `TypeScript` compiler is not "smart" enough at this point. When you do:

```
this.layouts[evt.value] = {
  ...this.layouts[evt.value]
}
```

It sees the `evt.value` as type `'contours' | 'museums'`, and it cannot infer that it twice is the same value, and twice will be the same object. Basically it's preventing you from doing:

```
this.layouts['contours'] = {
  ...this.layouts['museums']
}
```

In your example, you can do the following

```
this.layouts[evt.value].visibility = this.layouts[evt.value].visibility === 'visible'
  ? 'none'
  : 'visible';
```

But I suppose you do not want to do it this way, because change detection might not see that the object reference has changed. If that's an issue for you, I see no other way than to trick the compiler:

```
toggleLayer(evt: {value: 'contours' | 'museums'}) {
  const key = evt.value as 'contours';

  this.layouts[key] = {
    ...this.layouts[key],
    visibility: this.layouts[key].visibility === 'visible' ? 'none' : 'visible'
  };
}
```